# socks5: parsing failed

Tags: proxy

I'm facing the following problem:

I've updated Tor to version *3.5.7*.
Now, when I start Pidgin client (which has Tor proxy settings: localhost:9050), tor quits with this two warnings:

- Jan 16 12:18:44.000 [warn] socks5: parsing failed - invalid user/pass authentication message.
- Jan 16 12:18:44.000 [warn] socks5: parsing failed - invalid user/pass authentication message.

What could be the matter?

Answer (score 2):

Just received an answer at #tor IRC channel.
**You'd need to enter something to username and password fields in proxy settings.**

Hope that would help some of you too!